# How can I pass a 2-dimensional array from C# to C++?

Tags: c#, atl

The following method is in C++ (ATL COM dll)

```
Void Write( Const VARIANT *pData)
```

`pData` is a 2-dimensional array of data type `Variant`.

When I add this reference in a C# .NET project, the IDE shows the method as

```
Void Write( ref object pData);
```

How do I pass a 2-dimensional array from C#?

Comment: if the method `Write` of your ALT/COM object is declared `Void Write( Const VARIANT *pData)`, it will not be seen in the c# you are referencing your dll in. Is the signature `Void Write( Const VARIANT *pData)` right ? Or is it `STDMETHOD(Write)(VARIANT* pdata);` ? In my answer I am about to edit, I will assume that it is `STDMETHOD(Write)(VARIANT* pdata);`

Answer (score 0):

Array of `VARIANT`s fits itself well into VARIANT type. You can have it like this:

`void Write(VARIANT vData)`

where `vData.vt == (VT_ARRAY | VT_VARIANT)`, and `vData.parrray` is array data (safe array - it can by anydimensional, the array descriptor itself contains bounds and number of dimensions). C# will be able to get it right.

Answer (score 0):

There is a very good tutorial on how to exchange VARIANT's between unmanaged code (c++) and managed code (c# or .NET for instance) [here](http://limbioliong.wordpress.com/2011/09/04/using-variants-in-managed-code-part-1/) , it may help you.

**Edit**

As promised long time ago (I'm sorry I forgot) I edit my answer :

You can declare your 2D array in c# like this :

```
object thearray = new object[,] {{2.0, 1.0},{-3.0, 9.0}} ;
```

and pass it to you com method. You could also do this :

```
object[,] thetempmatrix = {{2.0, 1.0},{-3.0, 9.0}} ;
object thearray = thetempmatrix ;
```

Note that would you have rather defined

```
object[,] thearray = {{2.0, 1.0},{-3.0, 9.0}} ;
```

it would have worked also, but thearray wouldn't have been passed by reference : assume no const in your COM method signature, it would have been updated by your COM method, but at the exit of your COM method call, you would have got the same thearray as the one you passed. Of course, this last remark does not concern you, as you do have a const in your COM method signature.

Comment: Note that [link-only answers are discouraged](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info), SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Comment: Thx for your comment, I obviously lacked dynamism concern. ;-) I will therefore edit my answer right now.